# Activity extras - back

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem, a start new activity (Activity A) with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SezioniListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mat",mat);
startActivity(intent);
```

then I do what I need to do with mat object and then I start a new activity (Activity B)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SezioniListActivity.this, TestiListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sez",sez);
startActivity(intent);
```

the problem is that when I go back from this activity my app crash, I think that the problem is that when I go bak my old object "mat" is not the same of precedent obj, I think that it is null...how can I solve this problem?

Edit 3:

```
Main http://pastebin.com/2ad1nwPy
Sezioni http://pastebin.com/DqnVzG4a
Test http://pastebin.com/3hh2NmtT
```

Edit 2:

I get the value in this way:
(Activity A)
materia = (Materia) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("materia");

(Activity B)
sezione = (Sezione) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("sezione");

Edit 1:

```
02-02 00:46:36.109: D/Materia:(28022): viva
02-02 00:46:36.113: D/AndroidRuntime(28022): Shutting down VM
02-02 00:46:36.113: W/dalvikvm(28022): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41631ba8)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022): Process: com.example.testfun, PID: 28022
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testfun/com.example.testfun.SezioniListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at com.example.testfun.SezioniListActivity.onCreate(SezioniListActivity.java:30)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-02 00:46:36.140: E/AndroidRuntime(28022):    ... 11 more
02-02 00:46:52.718: I/Process(28022): Sending signal. PID: 28022 SIG: 9
02-02 00:46:53.273: D/OpenGLRenderer(28178): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: then why not put `mat` extra too? (if it's the problem) post a logcat can help

Comment: and what about some logcat output? :)

Comment: I edit the answer with the logcagt :) the problem is that this is my first android app, so a lot of thing are new :) until now I create only iOS app.

Comment: no, is a string and an array!

Comment: In the second `Intent` you are trying to start an `Activity` called `ListActivity.class`. Do you really have an `Activity` of that name? It is actually the name of one of the Android classes.

Comment: Show code how you getting mat object in middle activity

Comment: NO, sorry ListActivity is TestiListActivity, I correct my question!

Comment: What is at line com.example.testfun.SezioniListActivity.onCreate(SezioniListActivity.java:30? Also, are you saying that the object mat is null, or the intent is null?

Comment: I add on pastebin the code of the 3 activity, so you can read all :)